# Set button onClick based on users selected spinner item

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, spinner

In my application I have fragment which contains spinner, button, editText and multiple TextViews. This is my code for getting users selected item and displaying it:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //Get position
    int index = productSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    int[] tableSpoonList = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.tableSpoon);
    int[] glassList = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.glass);
    int[] teaSpoonList = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.teaSpoon);


    // Set the texts and defaults
    if (glassList[index] == 0) {
        typeGlass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        typeGlass.setText(getString(R.string.glass) + glassList[index] + getString(R.string.grams));
        typeGlass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (tableSpoonList[index] == 0) {
        typeTablespoon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        typeTablespoon.setText(getString(R.string.table_spoon) + tableSpoonList[index] + getString(R.string.grams));
        typeTablespoon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (teaSpoonList[index] == 0) {
        typeTeaspoon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        typeTeaspoon.setText(getString(R.string.tea_spoon) + teaSpoonList[index] + getString(R.string.grams));
        typeTeaspoon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

As I mentioned, I have an editText and a button. I want the user to enter a number in editText and do little calculations with the values then display it.

I came up with solution, setting buttons `onCLick` called *convert*:

```
public void convert (View view) {

    int userInput = Integer.parseInt(valueInput.getText().toString());

    if (userInput == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter the value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        double customTableSpoon = (1/tableSpoonList[index]) * userInput;
        typeTablespoon.setText(Double.toString(customTableSpoon));

    }

}
```

But as you can see, I cant get from

```
double customTableSpoon = (1/tableSpoonList[index]) * userInput;
```

*tableSpoonlist[index]*, because it is defined in spinners `onItemSelected`. However, If I define it outside before *convert* method

```
    //Get position
    int index = productSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    int[] tableSpoonList = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.tableSpoon);
    int[] glassList = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.glass);
    int[] teaSpoonList = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.teaSpoon);
```

I get crash when switching to that fragment, because

```
int index = productSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

returns null.

And I cant implement `onClick` in fragment, because I'm already implementing `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`.

Also, my spinner is created onCreateView:

```
    //Create spinner
    productSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.productSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.products_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    productSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    productSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

How can I get the spinners selected item so the user can "edit" it?

Comment: Why dont you make `tableSpoonList` *static* so you can access it anywhere?

Comment: @GrayCygnus problem is not with that really. I can declare it outside and everything will work, but the problem is with `int index = productSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();` because when I take it outside onItemSelected, I get java.lang.Null error.

Comment: Probably you get null because `productSpinner` is not defined in that context. Where are you defining it? If `tableSpoonList` works OK outside maybe you can try defining `productSpinner` somewhere accesible by other contexts (static may work). Another workaround could be that you store the `selectedItemPosition` when it is updated in an array or other structure that is `static`, and obtain your index by accessing that array instead of `productSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()`

Comment: @GrayCygnus I have `productSpinner` created onCreateView. Also static won't work.

Comment: Could you check if you are creating the spinner correctly? It is possible that your `findViewById(R.id.productSpinner)` is not finding your resource, thus returning null.

Comment: Are all of the methods part of one Fragment?